# Change color in tcxgrid column in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have two grids:

in one form  and compare between two value
 I need to change the color of the column in the grid when the two values are not equal

```
  TotalYear:=0 ;
  while not (mTblDetail.eof) do
  begin
       TotalYear:=TotalMonth +mTblDetail.FieldByName('Target_').AsFloat;
       mTblDetail.Next;
  end;
  TotalMonth:=0;
  while not(DataSet.Eof) do
  begin
      TotalMonth:=TotalMonth+DataSet.FieldByName('Target_').AsFloat;
      DataSet.Next;
  end;
```

I need to compare the two values and change the color

```
if(TotalYear<>TotalMonth) then
```

I tried to use this :

```
 DataSet.Columns[8].Color:= clRed
```

but is displays an error "Not Accepted". How Can change the color of a column of a Tcxgrid?

Comment: use `OnDrawColumnCell` event 
 `if (Column.Field.FieldName = 'MyFieldName') and  ...Field Value ...(TotalYear<>TotalMonth)  then Column.Color := clRed;`

Comment: Are those while loops your real code?  For one thing, you shouldn't need two while loops to increment two variables, you can do them in the same loop.  Another thing is that each time around the first loop, you overwrite the value of TotalValue (because its new value isn't based on its previous one).  If you want help, please post real code.  Btw, Delphi doesn't support HTML mark-up in its source code, which is why "DataSet.Columns[8].Color:= clRed <br>" won't compile

Comment: Wow really? Then see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078715/how-do-i-color-a-cxgrid-based-on-table-value

Comment: i Can't find property  color ? whet's error?

Comment: @user3420275, Datasets don't have any knowledge of UI elements, so colouring is the responsability of the component that displays the dataset, in your case the tcxgrid. Anyway, you should ask the component vendor, or do a search on their knowledgebase, [like I did](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A329).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloring in cxGrids is best done via cxStyles. Drop a TcxStyleRepository on the form and add some styles. You can assign them to the View.Styles.* properties or via events like OnGetContentStyle. I'm sure the online help contains an overview with screenshots and examples.